# best apex debug log tool

Tags: apex, debugging

What tool do you consider the best for analyzing Apex debug log? Are standard ones (Notepad++, Vim, etc) good? Any special plugins you think useful?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best debugging tool is the Developer Console.

There, you can:

- View Logs
- Set Checkpoints
- View and Analyze Timelines
- Run anonymous code
- Run test classes
- Run Queries

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex1_2.htm